# Sistema de questão em php

Tags: php

Ola pessoal estou tentando pensar em uma logica para fazer um sistema de questão com php porem eu travei em relação, quando o usuario termina de fazer questão 1  ele vai dar submit para próxima ai iria aparecer a questão numero 2 e assim por diante mas meu problema é que não estou conseguindo pensar como fazer com que assim que der submit ele vai para questão numero 2 sem ser a mesma de antes.

```
<?php

              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                  {

                      $db_questoes = $row['id_questao'];

                      if($db_questoes == 1 ){

                         echo nl2br($row['questao_biologia']);

                       }

                  }

          ?>
```

aqui ta só a primeira mas não consigo pensar como fazer para deixar automático,assim que termina questão 1 ,vai aparece a questão dois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução simples para o que pretende fazer é ter uma página que carrega uma questão por um parâmetro de *query string* e na validação da pergunta redireciona para a mesma página mudando apenas o parâmetro:

Ficheiro - perguntas.php?id=1

```
<?php
      $idPergunta = $_GET["id"];
      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "utilizador", "password", "bd");

      if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "Select * from questoes where id = $id")) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
      }
?>
<html>
....

<form action="verificarPergunta.php">
     <div><?=$row["categoria"]?></div>
     <div><?=$row["pergunta"]?></div>
....
```

Ficheiro - verificarPergunta.php

```
....
$proximaPergunta = $perguntaCorrente+1; //ou escolhendo de forma aleatória
if ($perguntaCerta == true){
     header("Location:perguntas.php?id=$proximaPergunta");
}
...
```

**Edit:** Editei a solução para completar o código com um exemplo de ir buscar a pergunta e mostrar no html. Por simplicidade não inclui alguns testes de validação tais como verificar se o `$_GET["id"]` existe, ou garantir que está corretamente preenchido com `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Esta solução irá no entanto navegar de página cada vez que o utilizador finaliza a pergunta. Se quiser contornar esta situação pode optar por uma solução mais complexa e fazer a submissão por *AJAX* e obter o *html* da próxima pergunta como resposta de *AJAX* e atualizar dinamicamente a página através de *Javascript*.

Outra solução simplista mas menos boa é simplesmente carregar todas as respostas relevantes para a página e ir mostrando e escondendo através de *Javascript* para mostrar só a que o utilizador vai.

Comment: Cara começou a me dar um luz em relação a isso,como você faria para mostra os dados no perguntas.php?

Comment: Faz uma consulta ao banco de dados com base no id da nova pergunta e coloca os valores nos sitios certos. Tipo `Select * from questoes where id=$idPergunta`. Depois coloca `$row["campoRelevante"]`nos locais do html que interessa. Para ir buscar a pergunta a query string utiliza `$idPergunta = $_GET["id"];`

Comment: pelo que entendi a paquina vai ser redirecionada com o id novo ,mas como capturar esse id quando ele for atualizar?exemplo perguntas.php?id=1 ai ele atualiza para perguntas.php?id=2 e como posso caputarar esse id 2 na pagina perguntas.php

Comment: Assim `$idPergunta = $_GET["id"];`. Com o array de get do PHP dá para aceder aos "parametros" do url, chamados de query string. Vou detalhar um pouco a resposta para esse cenário.